# How to log the compressed zip files when using a function in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am working on a shell script which should validate .gz files in multiple folders in linux and then gzip them if a particular file not zipped and if already the file is zipped, purge them with following condition.
a) All these files in folders have *.log..gz as extension

So i was using functions and find cmd to achieve the same.

Script seems to be working fine but its not logging the zipped files information to log file, however its spooling about already zipped files in the folder to log. is this the correct way using functions?

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR_PATH="/var/log"
LOG="/tmp/test.log"
VARLOG_PATH=("$DIR_PATH"{"Kevin","John","Robin","Pavan"})

fun_zip_log(){
for i in `find "$i" -type f \( -name "*.log.20*" 2>/dev/null \) `; do 
gzip "$i" ; done >> $LOG
}
fun_purge_log(){   
for i in `find "$i" -type f \( -name "log.20*" 2>/dev/null \) `; do rm -f 
"$i" ; done >> $LOG
}
validate_zip(){
for file in $i/*.gz
do
    if ! [ -f "$file" ];
    then
    echo "$file is getting zipped" >> $LOG
     fun_zip_log "$i" 

    else
    echo "$file is already zipped" >> $LOG
             fun_purge_log "$i" 

    fi
done
}
#MainBlock
for i in "${VARLOG_PATH[@]}"
do
if [ -d "$i" ] && [ "$(ls -A "$i" |wc -l )" -gt 0 ]; then
echo "Searching for files in directory : "$i" " >> $LOG
validate_zip "$i"
else
echo "No files exist in directory : "$i" " >> $LOG
fi
done
exit

####LOG FILE###
Searching for files in directory : /var/log/Kevin
[*.gz] is getting zipped.
Searching for files in directory : /var/log/John
/var/log/John/instrumentation.log.2018-06-20.gz is already zipped
/var/log/John/instrumentation.log.2018-06-21.gz is already zipped
No files exist in directory : /var/log/Robin
Searching for files in directory : /var/log/Pavan
[*.gz] is getting zipped.
```

Comment: please modify  LOG=/tmp/test.log to LOG="/tmp/test.log".

Comment: Hi Manoj, I just did that but still its not spooling the zipped files information to log. btw, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @ManojRana that does not make any difference

Comment: Your script is working fine here. I wouldn't use ls(1) to count files, and at least make it `/bin/ls`.

Comment: @Roadowl - in the log shared below for me its NOT displaying the files that are being zipped, so did you make any changes to that script? to spool the zipped files in log?

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It's not easy to tell what your problem is, as we cannot know what files you have in your log directories. I suspect that your filenames contain some characters special to the shell because your log output says `[*.gz]`. Make sure all variable substitutions are inside double quotes `"$i"`. If you have other stuff in your quotes as well, you can write it like `"other${i}characters"`.

Comment: Also, use speaking, different variable names like `log_file` or `log_directory` - You are silently overwriting the one global `i` multiple times (which does not matter here, but can lead to hard-to-find errors in other situations).

Answer (score 2):

Your code is very muddled and confusing. For example in this:

```
fun_purge_log(){   
for i in `find "$i" -type f \( -name "log.20*" 2>/dev/null \) `; do rm -f 
"$i" ; done >> $LOG
}

for file in $i/*.gz
do
    ...
    fun_purge_log "$i"
```

1. In the calling code you're looping setting a variable `file` but then passing the directory `"$i"` to your function to then try to find the files again.
2. Within fun_purge_log() you're ignoring the argument being passed in and then using the global variable `i` as both the directory argument to `find` and also to loop through the list of files output by `find` - why not pick a new variable name and use some local variables?
3. I can't imagine what you think `2>/dev/null` is going to do in `\( -name "*log.20*" 2>/dev/null \)`.
4. You're trying to append something to `$LOG` but you aren't printing anything to append to it.

Run your code through shellcheck (e.g. at shellcheck.net), read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001, https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs, and really just THINK about what each line of your code is doing. Correct the issues yourself and then let us know if you still have a problem. Oh, and by convention and to avoid clashing with other variables don't use all capitals for non-exported variable names and lastly use `$(command)` instead of `` `command` ``.

Comment: Hi Ed, Thanks for the advise.
1. variable "i" in fun_zip_log meant for the iteration to run over all the files that needs to be gzipped based on find the cmd, i will change the variable though.
2. I am not clear on how to achieve this sort of logic using functions, i mean validating for gz files in multiple folders and run them over a function to find the files based on condition.
3. i used 2>/dev/null to ignore the std output error as the script was throwing no such files or directory errors when condition is not matched in find cmd.

Can you pls throw some light in achieving this?

Comment: 1. Good. 2. Your problems have nothing to do with using functions, write the code inline and it'll have exactly the same issues. 3. There is no stderr produced within `\( -name "*log.20*" 2>/dev/null \)` and `find` certainly won't produce error messages about files it cant find, it just won't find them. Please just do what I suggested at the end of my answer and then post your corrected script if/when you need to ask a question about it afterwards.

Comment: Hi Ed, I have done some changes to my code and below are points that's needs some light to move on.1. find cmd does throw "No such file or directory " when i wont redirect stderr to 2>/dev/null 2. any update on printing each value that goes to forloop while validating the file format status and print the same to log (example: if it finds zip file, it should purge and print it to log and if it finds log it should zip and then print the same to log) any advise on how to achieve this?
Output
    find: `/var/log/kevin/log.20*': No such file or directory

Comment: changed code:    
fun_zip_log(){
    find "$i" -type f \( -name "*.log.20*" \)  ! -iname "*.gz"  -exec gzip '{}' \; >> $LOG_FILE  }

Comment: Think about it - how can `find` report `No such file or directory` when it itself is the thing searching for files and directories? It's like if you went counting cars in a parking lot and started yelling out "this car doesn't exist" once in a while. It makes no sense. Unless the ROOT directory you're passing to `find`, i.e. `"$i"` in `find "$i" ...`, doesn't exist and if that's happening then you certainly don't want to mask that by redirecting the message to stderr. Edit your question to post your corrected code and whatever questions you have.

Comment: how about this one to validate the zip file?
    func_val_zip(){
    PATH=($i)
    for val in $PATH/*.gz
    do
        if ! [ -f "$val" ];
        then
        echo "No gz files"
        elif [ ${val: -3} == ".gz" ]
        then
        echo "$val is already zipped"
        else
        echo "Not a valid format"
    fi
    done
    }

Comment: I've no idea, depends what the rest of your code looks like, etc. Again, update your question...